# Copy X lines from column to a new column in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have this information in an excel file, and i need that from 48 lines to 48 a new column are created, so i have this:

[image: I have]

And i need this:

[image: I need]

Is a copy & past each 48 lines in 50 000 lines (+/-), in VBA or not

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I use this function:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$20,ROW(C1)+(48*(COLUMNS($C$1:C$1)-1)))
```

on C1 cell and copy until C48 then copy to many columns works.

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
Sub test()
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim vDB
    Dim a()
    Dim i As Long, j As Integer, n As Integer
    
    Set Ws = ActiveSheet
    vDB = Ws.Range("a48", Ws.Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    
    For i = 1 To UBound(vDB, 1) Step 48
        n = n + 1
          ReDim Preserve a(1 To 48, 1 To n)
        For j = 0 To 47
            If i + j > UBound(vDB, 1) Then Exit For
            a(j + 1, n) = vDB(i + j, 1)
        Next j
    Next i
    Sheets.Add
    Range("a1").Resize(48, n) = a
    
End Sub
```